# PredicateBuilder nests OR clauses, causing nesting-too-deep issues for large predicates

Tags: c#, ormlite-servicestack, predicatebuilder

**Summary:** I'm using [PredicateBuilder](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Expressions/PredicateBuilder.cs) to `Or()` several expressions together, then sending that combined expression to [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite)'s `Select()` method. However, the generated SQL has a `WHERE` clause with so many nested parentheses that SQL Server throws an error. What can I do to work around this?

**Details:** I have a table `Foo` with two columns, `Bar` and `Baz`. If I have a collection of Bar/Baz values and I want to find all matching rows then I might (for example) issue the following SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Foo WHERE (Bar=1 AND Baz=1) OR (Bar=2 AND Baz=3) OR ...
```

Since I'm using [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite), I'm using [`PredicateBuilder`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite/Expressions/PredicateBuilder.cs) to generate a where clause for me:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Foo>();
foreach (var nextFoo in fooList)
    predicate = predicate.Or(foo => nextFoo.Bar == foo.Bar && 
                                    nextFoo.Baz == foo.Baz);
Db.Select(predicate);
```

If I execute this with **3 Foos in my list**, the generated SQL looks like this (cleaned up for brevity, but intentionally left on one line to make a point):

```
SELECT Bar, Baz FROM Foo WHERE ((((1=0) OR ((1=Bar) AND (1=Baz))) OR ((2=Bar) AND (3=Baz))) OR ((2=Bar) AND (7=Baz)))
```

Notice the leading parentheses? The `PredicateBuilder` continually parenthesizes the existing expression before adding the next one, so that `x` -> `(x) or y` -> `((x) or y) or z`, etc.

**My problem:** When I have dozens or hundreds of items to look up, the generated SQL has dozens or hundreds of nested parentheses, and SQL Server kicks it back with a `SqlException`:

> Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries.

So what can I do about this? I need the generated SQL's `WHERE` clause to be flattened (like my example query above) if I want to avoid the nesting exception. I know I can generate my own SQL dynamically and send it to OrmLite's `SqlList` method, but being forced to do that defeats half of OrmLite's value.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since SQL does not short-circuits `OR`s, you can convert an expression tree that looks like this

```
OR
 \
 OR
  \
  OR
   \
   OR
```

to an expression tree that looks like this:

```
        OR
      /    \
     /      \
    /        \
   OR        OR
 /   \     /    \
OR   OR   OR    OR
```

This is only a work-around: ideally, the framework should be able to deal with situations like that.

One way to construct a tree like this is to split your list recursively in halves, construct an "`OR`-tree" from each half recursively, and then combine the two "`OR`-tree"s with another `OR`:

```
Predicate ToOrTree(List<Foo> fooList) {
    if (fooList.Count > 2) {
        var firstHalf = fooList.Count / 2;
        var lhs = ToOrTree(fooList.Take(firstHalf).ToList());
        var rhs = ToOrTree(fooList.Skip(firstHalf).ToList());
        return lhs.Or(rhs);
    }
    Predicate res = PredicateBuilder.Create<Foo>(
        foo => fooList[0].Bar == foo.Bar &&  fooList[0].Baz == foo.Baz
    );
    if (fooList.Count == 2) {
        res = res.Or(
            foo => fooList[1].Bar == foo.Bar &&  fooList[1].Baz == foo.Baz
        );
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: This won't stop nesting entirely though, it will only manage it. For a large enough set, you may still encounter the `Sql nested too deeply` error if you list is large enough.

Comment: @Tyrsius Going from `N` levels of nesting to `Log2(N)` is a considerable jump, though: if the original solution required thirty levels of nesting to reach the limit, the workaround would require more than a billion items to get there!

Comment: While true, I am academically interested in *eliminating* nesting.

Comment: @Tyrsius You cannot do it with the current implementation of the .NET LINQ expressions, because `OR` is implemented as a binary operator, not as an `N`-ary one. That's why in a chain of two `OR`s one subtree is going to end up inside the other one, forcing the nesting no matter which way you go. I faced this issue in a small framework that I wrote several years ago on top of LINQ Expressions. I ended up solving the problem in the way that I described above, solving the issue at hand.

Comment: A creative answer, given the limitations. Solved my issue perfectly. The nesting limit for SQL Server is 32, so I'll just have to avoid querying more than 2^32 entities at a time (darn, shucks).